# Azure Web App with KeyVault References in App Settings

Tags: deployment, azure-web-app-service, azure-keyvault, azure-webapps

I have a Web App deployed with multiple App Settings, which reference secrets in Azure KeyVault. Everything is working fine until I redeploy the Web App. Then the reference becomes invalid.

[image]

As soon as I restart the app, everything works fine again.

What is the reason for that? And what can I do (during deployment) to avoid this behavior (besides restarting)?

**EDIT:**
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: how do you access the KV? Most importantly, how do you authenticate to KV? Are you using a managed identity?

Comment: @MichaelHoward The managed identity of the web app is added to the Access Policies of the Key Vault. The access to Secrets happens via https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references As written it works but stops working when being redeployed. Then I have to restart the app so that it works again.

Comment: have you used the KV diags:

In the portal, navigate to your app.
Select Diagnose and solve problems.
Choose Availability and Performance and select Web app down.
Find Key Vault Application Settings Diagnostics and click More info

Comment: Hey, a colleague and I will look into it for you... we're chatting tomorrow. I will post back once I know more...

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find an answer for that question but it also resolved itself automagically after a while. So I assume whatever it was, it has been fixed.